# SystemVerilog covergroup include coverpoint based on parameter

Tags: system-verilog

I'm creating coverage for my design and I want to reuse a covergroup definition   for multiple instances. The first instance should use all of the coverpoints as intended, but for the second instance, I want to exclude some of the coverpoints in the covergroup.

I was thinking I could use an input to the covergroup and iff () the unwanted coverpoints such that the first instance ties the input to 1 and the second instance ties the input to 0. However I think this will still show the coverpoints for the second instance as always not hit, and I want them to not be included at all.

```
covergroup cg_address(input bit enable) @ (posedge clock);
    address_check: coverpoint (address){
        bins addr_0 = {5'd0};
        bins addr_1 = {5'd1};
    }
    data_check: coverpoint (data) iff (enable){
        bins data_0 = {10'd0};
        bins data_1 = {10'd1};
    }
endgroup : cg_address

cg_address cg_address_inst0 = new(1'b1);
cg_address cg_address_inst1 = new(1'b0); //want this one to exclude data_check coverpoint
```

I know the above code won't work because the second instance will still have the data_check coverpoint, it will just never hit either bin because the enable is tied to 0. Is there any other way I can try to exclude the data_check coverpoint for the second instance?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

1. Set the weight of the coverpoint to 0.
2. Turn on `option.per_instance = 1;` for the covergroup.

For example:

```
covergroup cg_address(input bit enable) @ (posedge clock);
    option.per_instance = 1;
    address_check: coverpoint (address){
        bins addr_0 = {5'd0};
        bins addr_1 = {5'd1};
    }
    data_check: coverpoint (data) {
        option.weight = enable;
        bins data_0 = {10'd0};
        bins data_1 = {10'd1};
    }
endgroup : cg_address

cg_address cg_address_inst0 = new(1);
cg_address cg_address_inst1 = new(0); //want this one to exclude data_check coverpoint
```